# NSURLSessionDataTask: Application crashes in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I am using a `NSURLSessionDataTask` in a `NSOperationQueue` which leads to a crash of my application.

Unfortunately after changing many queue related parameters and reading through the documentation, I am still unable to find the reason of my bug.

I would appreciate any help and hints from you!

This is my **AppDelegate.m** (Cocoa) where I set up the queue and start the background operation. Please note that the operation has a completion handler:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *queue;

- (IBAction)startProcess:(id)sender {

    self.queue = [NSOperationQueue new];
    self.queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1; // serial queue

    MyOperation *myOperation = [[MyOperation alloc]initWithSymbol:@"abc"
        withCompletion:^(NSError *error, NSString *result) {
        NSLog(@"Process completed: %@",result);
    }];
    [self.queue myOperation];
}
```

This is **MyOperation.h**:

```
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation
```

**MyOperation.m:**

```
@interface MyOperation ()

typedef void(^completionBlock)(NSError *error, NSString *result);
@property (strong, nonatomic) completionBlock completionBlock;

@end

@implementation MyOperation

- (id)initWithSymbol:(NSString*)symbol withCompletion:
        (void(^)(NSError *error, Order *order))completionBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _symbol = symbol;
        _completionBlock = completionBlock;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)main {
  MyObject *myObject = [[MyObject alloc]init];
  [myObject downloadData:self.symbol withCompletion:
         ^(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

      //... }];
```

And this is **MyObject.m** where the application crashes in the method `-downloadData`:

```
- (void)downloadData:self:(NSString*)symbol 
      withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary* results, NSError *error))completionBlock
   // ...
  NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
      requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.baseUrl 
      stringByAppendingString:path]]];

  NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = 
      [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];

  NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession 
     sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self 
     delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]];

   NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = 
      [session dataTaskWithRequest:request 
      completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, 
      NSError *error) {
    // **** THE APP CRASHES HERE RIGHT AFTER THE DATATASK STARTS. ****
    // The completion block never gets called.
    completionBlock(results, nil);
}];
[dataTask resume];
}
```

This is the crash log (`Thread 2, 0__cxa_throw`):

```
    libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_throw:
0x7fff8f6e1bdf:  pushq  %rbp
0x7fff8f6e1be0:  movq   %rsp, %rbp
0x7fff8f6e1be3:  pushq  %r15
0x7fff8f6e1be5:  pushq  %r14
0x7fff8f6e1be7:  pushq  %r13
0x7fff8f6e1be9:  pushq  %r12
0x7fff8f6e1beb:  pushq  %rbx
0x7fff8f6e1bec:  pushq  %rax
0x7fff8f6e1bed:  movq   %rdx, %r14
0x7fff8f6e1bf0:  movq   %rsi, %r15
0x7fff8f6e1bf3:  movq   %rdi, %rbx
0x7fff8f6e1bf6:  callq  0x7fff8f6e17f4            ; __cxa_get_globals
0x7fff8f6e1bfb:  movq   %rax, %r12
0x7fff8f6e1bfe:  callq  0x7fff8f6e2180            ; std::get_unexpected()
0x7fff8f6e1c03:  movq   %rax, -0x60(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c07:  callq  0x7fff8f6e21ba            ; std::get_terminate()
0x7fff8f6e1c0c:  leaq   -0x20(%rbx), %r13
0x7fff8f6e1c10:  leaq   0x44(%rip), %rcx          ; __cxxabiv1::exception_cleanup_func(_Unwind_Reason_Code, _Unwind_Exception*)
0x7fff8f6e1c17:  movabsq $0x434c4e47432b2b00, %rdx
0x7fff8f6e1c21:  movq   %rax, -0x58(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c25:  movq   %r15, -0x70(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c29:  movq   %r14, -0x68(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c2d:  movq   %rdx, -0x20(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c31:  movq   $0x1, -0x78(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c39:  incl   0x8(%r12)
0x7fff8f6e1c3e:  movq   %rcx, -0x18(%rbx)
0x7fff8f6e1c42:  movq   %r13, %rdi
0x7fff8f6e1c45:  callq  0x7fff8f6e49cc            ; symbol stub for: _Unwind_RaiseException
0x7fff8f6e1c4a:  movq   %r13, %rdi
0x7fff8f6e1c4d:  callq  0x7fff8f6e1c7f            ; __cxa_begin_catch
0x7fff8f6e1c52:  movq   -0x58(%rbx), %rdi
0x7fff8f6e1c56:  callq  0x7fff8f6e21c9            ; std::__terminate(void (*)())
```

**MyObject** acts as an API to a web service and has methods to GET data from it.

**MyOperation** contains the business logic and controls the requests which are being sent to the API.

Imagine **MyObject** being the API to a stock broker and the methods being: getSharePrice, placeOrder and cancelOrder.

**MyOperation** defines the logic, e.g. `sharePrice = getSharePrice(symbol:"AAPL"); while (sharePrice < 300) placeOrder("AAPL", 50) until allSharesBought = 1000.`

**Thank you for your help!!**

Comment: What would a non-severe crash look like?

Comment: @Matt: Something more friendly which makes it easier to debug :-) I love your books btw.

Comment: :) Can you get it to be any more friendly by setting a global exceptions breakpoint? I expect to see _something_ in the log. What you are showing doesn't look like a log. Or at least not the start of the log, which is where the useful info usually is.

Comment: Also, could you say a little more about what you're trying to do? One does't usually need an NSOperationQueue in order to use NSURLSession and NSURLSessionDataTask.

Comment: @Matt: I have updated my question and added a exception breakpoint to get more (debug) data. Unfortunately, the log does not look any better. :-(

Comment: But what is the NSOperationQueue for? That's what I'm trying to find out. NSURLSession already does its networking in the background, and you can easily arrange for the delegate messages to come back to you on a background thread, so why confuse yourself with an extra layer of backgrounding?

Comment: I did not find a better structured way to separate between operations (buy shares) and the underlying web service requests. It should be possible to simultaneously buy shares at different brokers (=different MyObjects, each one has a different API) and to have different business logic for each trade (different operation queues, e.g. Buy Apple < 350 and sell IBM > 100).

Comment: @matt I can't speak for Alex, but I always wrap my `NSURLSessionTask` requests in operations, that way I can control how many run concurrently without having them risk timing out, as well as gracefully handle dependencies and the like. It's more work to wrap it in an operation, but I think it's best practice.

Comment: @Rob I would still press for a less confusing (i.e. less heavily threaded) alternative where you hand data in at the start of the request and pull it out at the end. This will allow you to do sequential requests by using a completion handler, but the completion handler is attached to the request, not to some object as an instance variable where there may be threading / access issues. See the answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18992257/nsurlsession-delegation-how-to-implement-my-custom-sessiondelegate-class-accord

Comment: And see my code example here: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/master/bk2ch24p842downloader/ch37p1099downloader/MyDownloader.m

Comment: @matt I hear you, and for one off tasks, I do something very similar. But I think subclassing `NSOperation`-based is a richer solution. Perhaps, we'll just have to agree to disagree. :)

Comment: @Rob actually we agree. But, as the OP's question shows, using an NSOperation is harder! - Also I think we probably agree that the _real_ issue that there are some design flaws in the whole session / task / delegate architecture.

Comment: @matt Agreed! The `NSURLSession` architecture a hot mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could get a crash like you describe if you fail to make your operation a "concurrent" operation (i.e. one that returns true to `isConcurrent` and posts `isFinished` only after the asynchronous process is done). Without that, your `MyOperation` object may be deallocated too soon because the operation is "finished" when the the initiation of the request is finished, rather than waiting for the response. For a discussion on concurrent operations, see the [Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW8) section of *Operation Queues* chapter of the *Concurrency Programming Guide.*

Furthermore, you might also want to make sure you maintain a strong reference to `myObject`.

Thus:

```
@interface MyOperation ()

typedef void(^MyOperationCompletionBlock)(NSError *error, NSString *result);

@property (copy, nonatomic) MyOperationCompletionBlock myOperationCompletionBlock;
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyObject *myObject;

@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isFinished)  BOOL finished;
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, getter = isExecuting) BOOL executing;

@end

@implementation MyOperation

@synthesize finished  = _finished;
@synthesize executing = _executing;

- (id)initWithSymbol:(NSString*)symbol withCompletion:(MyOperationCompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _symbol = symbol;
        _myOperationCompletionBlock = completionBlock;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)start
{
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        self.finished = YES;
        return;
    }

    self.executing = YES;

    self.myObject = [[MyObject alloc]init];
    [self.myObject downloadData:self.symbol withCompletion:^(NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

        NSString *result = ... // presumably you're extracting this from `results` dictionary

        if (self.myOperationCompletionBlock)
            self.myOperationCompletionBlock(error, result);

        [self completeOperation];  // this is the key; post the `isFinished` notification when done
    }];
}

- (void)completeOperation
{
    self.executing = NO;
    self.finished  = YES;
}

#pragma mark - NSOperation methods

- (BOOL)isConcurrent
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)setExecuting:(BOOL)executing
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
    _executing = executing;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isExecuting"];
}

- (void)setFinished:(BOOL)finished
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
    _finished = finished;
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"isFinished"];
}

@end
```

Also, when you make your session, if you're not writing delegate methods (which is implied by your use of the completion block rendition of `dataTaskWithRequest`) you should use `[NSURLSession sharedSession]` or `[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration]` (but no delegate specified). Specifying a `delegate` of `nil` can cause problems. Thus:

```
- (void)downloadData:self:(NSString*)symbol withCompletion:(void(^)(NSDictionary* results, NSError *error))completionBlock
{
    // ...
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.baseUrl stringByAppendingString:path]]];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

        // **** THE APP CRASHES HERE RIGHT AFTER THE DATATASK STARTS. ****
        // The completion block never gets called.
        completionBlock(results, nil);
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

---

Unrelated, I'd also suggest:

1. Don't call your block property `completionBlock`. `NSOperation` already has a `completionBlock` property (with a different signature). In my example above, I renamed this to `myOperationCompletionBlock`.
2. Apple advises that you declare your block property with the `copy` memory semantic. If you use ARC, that's what it does, regardless, so they suggest declaring your property with the memory semantic that best reflects what's going on.

Comment: BTW, I'd also suggest that you (a) change your `MyObject` class to save the `NSURLSessionDataTask` object; (b) provide `MyObject` a `cancel` method so that request can be canceled; and (c) write a `cancel` method for your operation that will cancel the `MyObject` request. Focus on fixing your crash first, but you generally want to make sure that your `NSOperation`-based requests gracefully handle cancellation requests (even if you don't anticipate needing to cancel requests at this point).

Comment: thank you for your great answer!! I have changed my code to reflect your recommendations and ideas. However, it still crashes at exactly the same line. I believe it could have to do with how my `NSURLSessionDataTask` is configured (`NSURLSessionConfiguration`) and that it runs in a background queue where it tries to span a new background thread. Do you have any ideas on what could be the problem there?

Comment: @AlexR My working thesis was that your code snippet of your original question could crash because either the `MyOperation` or `MyObject` instances could be prematurely deallocated (because you're not doing anything to keep them around). Perhaps you have other issues as well, but that's what I was focusing on. I'd suggest writing `dealloc` methods for both of these classes and make sure that they're not being deallocated too soon (which could happen if your operation wasn't a concurrent operation, or if your `MyOperation` neglected to maintain a strong reference to `MyObject`).

Comment: @AlexR But also make sure that your `NSURL` object is non-`nil` (if you had invalid characters, such as spaces, in the URL, or if it was otherwise malformed, the `NSURL` would not be properly instantiated) and that the `NSURLRequest` was non-`nil`, too. If either of those were `nil`, that might also make the `NSURLSessionTask` crash immediately.

Comment: I checked `NSURLRequest` and `NSURL`: Both look fine. Is it correct to set `NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:nil delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]];`?

Comment: @AlexR No. Use `[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig]` if you're going to use the completion block rendition of the task factory (i.e. you're not writing any delegate methods). If you were going to use delegates (which you aren't, AFAIK), then specify the `delegate` as `self` (and obviously, then implement all of the relevant delegate methods), but then use `dataTaskWithRequest` without completion block. But specifying a session `delegate` of `nil` is _not_ the same thing as instantiating the `NSURLSession` without a `delegate`.

Comment: BTW, if you were going to implement the delegate methods, BTW, putting it at the request object would not be the right place anyway. So, keeping it simple, instantiate a delegate-less session (either `[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig]` or, easier, `[NSURLSession sharedSession]`), and then use the completion block rendition of `dataTaskWithRequest`. While the delegate-based approach is richer, it's a little more complicated to do right.

Comment: `NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];` was the solution to my problem!